# Is it possible to change query after binding a parameter in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

For example:

if I have this query: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE test = ?`

then I bind a parameter, can I now add something to my query?

If this is possible please give me an example in PHP.

Comment: Prepare another query.

Comment: But what if I wanted to for example add 'AND anotherTest = ?' to the end of the query?

Comment: Prepare a **NEW** query. Over.

Comment: @LorenzoDeBie Then you have prepared the query too soon. Only prepare it once you know exactly what it is going to look like.

Comment: Is it then possible to only bind one parameter at a time? after I have the full query?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem: I made the whole query and then checked if the param was needed and then bound them one per one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't possible. What do you need?

Comment: I have all these variables I need to test against a DB but only if they are not the default value, so what I was trying is what I asked above (I wanted to work with prepared statements since it is user input)

Comment: @Lorenzo That's right. Just enclose query to if($variable !== "default') or something like this

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.  You'll have to prepare a new query.