# MySQL SELECT COUNT returning NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the number of comments on a particular item.

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(r_value) FROM ratings WHERE r_snippet=? AND r_value=3 OR r_value=2");
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(c_id) FROM comments WHERE c_snippet=?");

foreach ($snippets as $snippet){

    $s_id = $snippet['s_id'];
    $s_thumb = $snippet['s_thumb'];

    $stmt1->bind_param("i",$s_id);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->bind_result($numLikes);
    $stmt1->fetch();

    $stmt2->bind_param("i",$s_id);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->bind_result($numComments);
    $stmt2->fetch();

?>

    ** HTML here **    

<?php 

}

$stmt1->close();
$stmt2->close();

?>
```

`$numLikes` works fine, but `$numComments` seems to be returning NULL (from `var_dump`) and I'm not sure why. The SQL in phpMyAdmin works fine and returns the number of comments...

Comment: post minimal code, check and replace bind_param with hardcoded values. Also, put a single query and check for errors: `printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt1->error);`

Comment: `Error: Attempt to read a row while there is no result set associated with the statement.`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want change this for your first query

```
... AND r_value=3 OR r_value=2
```

To

```
... AND (r_value=3 OR r_value=2)
```

OR THIS

```
... AND r_value IN (2,3)
```

---

But for the second query try something simple just for debug

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE c_snippet=10");
```

then

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE c_snippet=10");
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't fix the `$numComments` being NULL issue

Comment: OK, I just realize the problem is the second query. Try something simple for debug like I update in my answer

Comment: I did the first debug, and it worked only if I placed all the `$stmt2` s outside of the foreach loop

Comment: @user3040456 then debug the variable `$snippet['s_id'];` maybe isnt the value you expect? because query looks ok

Comment: I printed it, and it's fine for each

Comment: If I put the `$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("...")` inside the foreach loop, I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean`

Comment: Looks like you have to prepare a query for each bind variable.   check this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892748/is-it-possible-to-change-query-after-binding-a-parameter-in-mysql)